# How to synchronize with outlook calendar in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

i have an **exchange 2010** mail server, and i open the accounts on **outlook 2010**.

i want to connect to the **calendar folder** and get the upcoming **appointments/meetings** details.

i am using `java-mail 1.4.5` , can i do that with `javamail` or there are other free libraries that can do that ?

please advise how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make use of all the features offered by the Exchange server, you can use the [EWS (Exchange Web Services) Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) from Microsoft.

Comment: Why didn't you just open the page I linked to and read the first paragraph? "This API gives developers programmatic access to Exchange Server 2007 SP1 and above."

Comment: i saw that, and i saw other people mentioning that it doesn't work with exchange 2010 against what the document says.

Comment: Who are "other people" and what is not supposed to work with Exchange 2010?